# Using and escaping wpa_cli set_network command in a bash script

Tags: shell-script, wpa-supplicant, wpa-cli

One can connect to a wifi network through `wpa_supplicant`'s command line interface, `wpa_cli`. `wpa_cli` has 2 modes of operation : interactive, and normal. 
In normal mode, one must pass the desired command through `wpa_cli`'s arguments.

For exemple, to connect to a network, one must execute the following commands (as root) :

```
wpa_cli add_network
> 0 # this is the new network's ID
wpa_cli set_network 0 ssid '"SSID_HERE"'
wpa_cli set_network 0 psk '"PASSPHRASE_HERE"'
wpa_cli enable_network 0
```

All of these operations can be scripted. But `wpa_cli` requires, for `set_network ssid` and `set_network psk`, that both the SSID and passphrase are escaped by a single quote **and** a double quote, like this : `'"ssid"'`.

However, this escape format is hard to respect in a script when you want to replace the ssid by a variable's value, and wpa_cli keeps returning a FAIL exit status, instead of OK. The following patterns have been tried :

```
ssid '"$ssid"' # doesn't work, sets SSID to "$ssid" instead of $ssid's value
ssid \'"$ssid"\' # doesn't work
```

Hence, my question is : How to put the ssid in a variable in a script, and use it as a parameter to give wpa_cli a SSID/passphrase ?

Comment: `ssid "'$ssid'"` should work.

Comment: Nope, wpa_cli returns `FAIL` too. This is very weird, though, because this should be equivalent to my solution...

Comment: Oh, just noticed I made a typo - the working pattern is `'"' $ssid '"'` instead of `"'" $ssid "'"`... Will edit my answer

Answer (score 2):

The following pattern is working for me, but I do not know if it is secure :

```
wpa_cli set_network 0 ssid '"'$ssid'"'
```

I guess only the ' ' are kept, along with `$ssid`'s value.